# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), we are facing a crash when we are reusing the SurfaceView for playing video

Tags: android, frameworks, surfaceview

we are facing this issue wherin trying to reuse the surfaceView for playing the video

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10 in
tid 5971 (hwuiTask1), pid 4526 (com.example.tv)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint:
'Project/hsw4026atl/hsw4026atl:9/PTT1.210208.001/2.3.0-
21042717:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 4526, tid: 5971, name: hwuiTask1  >>> com.example.tv <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
Cause: null pointer dereference

```
        r0  00000000  r1  7b6fa440  r2  7b17f32c  r3  00000000
        r4  8877d100  r5  7b17f360  r6  7b17f338  r7  00000000
        r8  8877d104  r9  7b17f420  r10 13a56118  r11 13f1a020
        ip  a4935e24  sp  7b17f328  lr  a491ac6b  pc  a491ac6e"-*
```

backtrace:

```
    #00 pc 0005dc6e  /system/lib/libgui.so -(android::SurfaceComposerClient::Transaction::getLayerState(android::sp<android::SurfaceControl> const&)+286)
   #01 pc 0005dfeb  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::SurfaceComposerClient::Transaction::deferTransactionUntil(android::sp<android::SurfaceControl> const&, android::sp<android::Surface> const&, unsigned long long)+22)
   #02 pc 000a537f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::nativeDeferTransactionUntilSurface(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long long, long long, long long, long long)+62)
   #03 pc 003acc89  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x38a000) (android.view.SurfaceControl.nativeDeferTransactionUntilSurface+152)
   #04 pc 009b8a23  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x38a000) (android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction.deferTransactionUntilSurface+114)
   #05 pc 00b143a7  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x38a000) (android.view.SurfaceView.applySurfaceTransforms+110)
   #06 pc 00b166d9  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x38a000) (android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurfacePosition_renderWorker+240)
   #07 pc 0041cb75  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
   #08 pc 003f5b09  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+224)
   #09 pc 000a100d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+136)
   #10 pc 00354ea1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
   #11 pc 00355e51  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+316)
   #12 pc 00279c5b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+482)
   #13 pc 000794cb  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+38)
   #14 pc 000a11df  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZZN7androidL46android_view_RenderNode_requestPositionUpdatesEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectxS3_EN26SurfaceViewPositionUpdater21doUpdatePositionAsyncExiiii+122)
   #15 pc 000a135d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcINS_6__bindINS_8__mem_fnIMZN7androidL46android_view_RenderNode_requestPositionUpdatesEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectxS8_E26SurfaceViewPositionUpdaterFvxiiiiEEEJPS9_xiiiiEEENS_9allocatorISE_EEFvvEEclEv+52)
   #16 pc 0037c61d  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CacheManager::SkiaTaskProcessor::onProcess(android::sp<android::uirenderer::Task<bool>> const&)+14)
   #17 pc 0037ae17  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::TaskProcessor<bool>::process(android::sp<android::uirenderer::TaskBase> const&)+38)
   #18 pc 0034814b  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::TaskManager::WorkerThread::threadLoop()+110)
   #19 pc 0000c189  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+292)
   #20 pc 0006f1c3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+82)
   #21 pc 00064303  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
   #22 pc 0001df8d  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)
   BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_00 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
   ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.tv/.MainActivity
```